# Cannot commit to Git repository in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: xcode, git

When I try to commit I get the following error:

```
The working copy "Chord Attack" failed to commit files. fatal:
Will not add file alias 'Chord Attack/GameResources/GUI/Chord Attack/chordattackbg.png'
('Chord Attack/GameResources/GUI/Chord Attack/ChordAttackBG.png' already exists in index)
```

I can't even find that file in my directory or anywhere on my computer. I deleted that from  my project a long time ago. I even recreated my project and manually added files one by one and some how this happened again. I saw another post that said to delete the file and manually re-add it, but it didn't work. Currently, the chordattackbg.png file is in my project. I tried deleting that and then committing, but the same error came up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case issue (chordattackbg.png vs. ChordAttackBG.png), as described in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51346#51619).

You would need to:

```
git mv ChordAttackBG.png foo
git mv foo chordattackbg.png
git commit -m "Rename ChordAttackBG.png to chordattackbg.png"
```

Then you would apply your modifications to `chordattackbg.png`, add and commit.

Here the solution was to:

- clone the local repo again,
- cleanup its content,
- rename the file (`ChordAttackBG.png` to `chordattackbg.png`),
- add the new modifications to `chordattackbg.png`,
- re-open the project in XCode from the new clone.

Comment: Okay, finally, something worked. I've clone it. Weird, I see a lot of old files in the cloned version that I don't currently have in my project.

Comment: @02fentym maybe it is best to work in that new clone: cleanup old files, `git add -A`, `git commit`, and see if you can commit your `chordattackbg.png` there.

Comment: So I should add chordattackbg.png into the cloned repository then try to commit it? Should I delete ChordAttackBG.png first?

Comment: @02fentym maybe try to rename it first (as in my original answer). Then, if the case is right, report your modifications in the renamed `chordattackbg.png`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot. Okay, it looks like it has worked! Should I try to commit via Xcode now?

Comment: @02fentym no, first commit with the command line, then re-import the project (from `rootfolder2`) in XCode, and see if you can go on from there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I already committed via the command line. Can I now open the project file via Xcode? When you say "re-import" the project what's the difference between that and just simply reopening the project via the .xcodeproj file?

Comment: @02fentym Re-opening is fine, as long as you are taking the `.xcodeproj` from `rootFolder2`, and not the one from your original repo `rootFolder`.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm doing. From my understanding, I should just delete the original repo since it seems that something is corrupt right?

Comment: @02fentym delete or at least rename its rootFolder for now (just in case), and delete it later.

Comment: Awesome...thank you so much for having patience with me throughout this ordeal.

Comment: @02fentym no problem, glad you made it work in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem deleting this file:

/path/to/project/folder/.git/index.lock

Then I could commit from Xcode with no problems. Hope this helps!